# Python how to parse a json usng tags in a loop

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, csv

I have a list of 155 json tags and a json file associated with it. The idea is to parse the json file using the predetermined tags and if one of the tags is not available in the json string then use null.

I am using `python 2.7` and native json parser. I need to convert the json in to csv. The problem here is am trying to extract json fields using tag from a file but I am having issues evaluating the tags. I am getting a key error.

I have a list of json schema like below.

```
json Schema file:
jsonTag.tagb,csv_columnA
jsonTag2.Id,csv_columnB
jsonTag2.Id.description,csv_columnC
```

I want to loop through the above and get all the json tags.

Use the json tag to extract from the json file. the above is just an example we have around 155 tags and complext nested json.

Below is the method I have in python which gets a schema (tags) from a different method using an ordered `Dict` format which I need to use to extract the json

```
    def write_to_csv(self):

            myvars = self.generate_schema() #gets schema in orderedDict key value parir
            header = []
            values = []

            with open('sample_json.json','r') as json_file: #read json file row by row json string

                 json_string = json_file.read().splitlines()

                 for json_line in json_string:

                     json_parsed=json.loads(json_line) #parse each row

                     for key, value in myvars.items():

                         values.append(json_parsed[value]) #evalueat the tag and append to an array which i will use it to do csv write row.

                     print values
```

Below is the error i am getting now.

```
OUTPUT:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./parse_nested_json.py", line 86, in <module>
    main()
  File "./parse_nested_json.py", line 83, in main
    parse.write_to_csv()
  File "./parse_nested_json.py", line 63, in write_to_csv
    values.append(json_parsed[value.strip('\"')])
KeyError: "['trackingEvent']['barcode']"


Expected output:
csv
csv_columnA,csv_columB,csv_columnC
1223,abc,aaa
234,asd,ssaa
..etc
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi so the error here is in the line `json_parsed[value]` as your json might not have the value as the key in it. So you must first try `value in json_parsed` and if it returned true then append it else append null.

Comment: Hi thanks the issue is I am trying to get at json_parser['tag1']['id']  the value is a parameter which contains the text ['tag1']['id']. So i am looping though a file with tags like ['xxx']['xxx']['id'] and querying the json file using the json loads object json_parse[value]

Comment: The way you mentioned i will be able to loop though the json parent tags but our json is nessted and we have determined set of tags that we are trying to extract from json so we need to loop though out tag first and extract json.

Comment: In short given a list of json tags say ['enquiry']['id] , ['enquiry']['type'] will we be able to read a json file for the above tags without hardcoding the tags to jsonloads object

Comment: can you please explain with a good and concrete example ? 
I will be able to help you more